# Bijection between \$ \mathbb N \$ and at-most-\$n\$-ary trees

Tags: code-golf, math, open-ended-function

### Background

Related: [a golflang theory I posted in TNB a while ago](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/240?m=58722627#58722627)

**At-most-\$n\$-ary trees** are rooted trees where each internal node has between 1 and \$n\$ children (inclusive). Two trees are considered identical only if the shapes exactly match without re-ordering each node's children. In other words, the left-to-right order of children matters.

For example, the following is an example of an at-most-ternary tree (each node is marked with its out-degree, the leaves being zeros):

```
    2
   / \
  1   2
  |  / \
  3  0 1
 /|\   |
0 0 0  0
```

Related OEIS sequences: [A006318](https://oeis.org/A006318) is the number of at-most-binary trees having \$n\$ internal nodes, and [A107708](https://oeis.org/A107708) is for at-most-ternary trees.

Note that a single-node tree is a valid at-most-\$n\$-ary tree for any value of \$n\$, since it has no internal nodes.

### Challenge

Write a function or program that, given a positive integer \$n\$ (1st input), maps a natural number (2nd input) to a unique at-most-\$n\$-ary tree. It must be a bijection; every tree must have a unique natural number that maps to the tree. Only the code going from a number to a tree is considered for scoring, but it is recommended to provide the opposite side to demonstrate that it is indeed a bijection.

The output format for the tree is flexible (nested arrays, string/flat array representations including parentheses or prefix notation). You can also choose the "natural number" to start at 0 or 1.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 107 bytes

```python
def f(n,x):
 def g(m):r=y[0]%m;y[0]//=m;return[g(n+1)for i in y*r]
 y=[x-1];return x and g(n)+[f(n,*y)]or[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzLCsMgEADv@Yq9FNwkJbX2meCXiIdCYpqDa1gs6NfbCj0NA8PsOb4DqVLmxYET1CccG6iyCo8j62xO9uCnimHQfuIlfpjMKqiT6ALDBhtBbtk2kLVJR2n/DSR40fz7EHamrtuMNrCxZeeNonBC9fB83G/XizpLxPIF)

Naturals start at 0. Inverse map:

```python
def g(n,t):
 x=0;y=1;q=t,
 while q:*q,u=q;x+=len(u)*y;y*=n+bool(q);q+=u[::-1]
 return x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VUpJCsMgFN17ir90KjRkp/yTBDelNgmIRlGqp7djSvoWb95aXoIfe7/aG8zUy8wUgYpn3XDQEbMkcF9WZyEqHmXBqKtAZz0tjDfdOHpxCcHRyHQUWCalToMhkGwuyUPtW1p9pjMdJUwvmKear9/zZN7th/bDwfxXx/NvYKw/AA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 32 bytes

```
⁴‘ßƊḢd¥ɼṪ$Ð¡Ḋ
¹©ṛ’ɼ⁴çƊḢɼÐ¿ḊṚṭƒ“”
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9R45ZHDTMOzz/W9XDHopRDS0/uebhzlcrhCYcWPtzRxXVo56GVD3fOftQw8@QeoMrDy8HKTu4Byu8Hyj/cOevhzrXHJj1qmPOoYe7/hzu2HV5@dNLDnTN0HB417jjV/ahpjTcQR/7/b2hg8N8YAA)

A dyadic link taking \$n\$ as the right argument and a natural number as the left argument and returning a nested list.

This uses the same algorithm as [@AndersKaseorg’s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/233281/42248) (so be sure to vote that one up too!). However, despite Jelly’s Python base, this was not trivial to translate. The main function was changed from using recursion to a while loop followed by a `reduce`, but a recursive method was preserved for the subsidiary function (`g()` in the Python code).

Full explanation to follow.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 83 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,x:[f(n,int(str(~-x//n)[~i::~(x%n)][::-1]or 0))for i in range(x%n+(x>0))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYzLDoIwEEV/pRuTNkKYmb6b6I8QFhhFSXQglQVu@PUKOYu7ODdn/i2viXUpw@Xdf273XnC1pnaQXI28yO@S5VavTcOq3caUNrmeWHVtSjV2Uxag1LDPKEYWuefn4/BnuV530ZU5H41BmkpY0t4Y7YE8gg20gxHImagtBnI6GOcQgrEeEEiDjt45sEiRMETYDzY6b4JDUqr8AQ)

0 yields the trivial tree with only one node. Other numbers are broken down into \$ 1 \le k \le n\$ and \$ x' \ge 0\$ using modulo; \$ k\$ is used as the number of children of the root, and the decimal digits of \$ x' \$ are distributed among those children by taking every \$ k \textrm{th} \$ digit starting from different low places, recursively applying the same procedure for each child.

Inverse:

```python
import itertools
def invf(n, l):
    assert type(n) == int and n > 0 and type(l) == list and len(l) <= n
    return 0 if not l else int(''.join(''.join(t) for t in itertools.zip_longest(*[str(invf(n, m))[::-1] for m in l], fillvalue='0'))[::-1]) * n + (len(l) - 1 or n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZLRboMgFIbvfYpzp3S2abNdmbkXMWYxKW4seDBAm3Qv7xCrAuK4QPB8/@Hn1/6hvwW@DgPreiE1ME2lFoKr5EpbYHhvM8yBkyIBMxqlTBn0o6cZEihLQ2ho8AoIH3C2K1vktsiZmqqc4vjqvQS0fSTVN4lGwFpAoYED5YqOzbI0Pf0IhstTE2iFBOMMV3OnX9Z/coFfVOnsUCkts9lqR0hVFMdLbWXdKON1Di3j/N7wGy3TczojBA7G@AtkT39HuIARIRl6OXqxPd/ypFqG6VTVdnIX4ft5Y@ZnOUYt6mk3If5u5VZwKs@0g6/cAm1A3114UujsHyzwM13Wu8duJts7xdt77qvwSD@GeLKec1fltPVTjscRJFnFw9le1ZFP2j3EMeCAkaCjH3/v39uJdByEDH8)